I get an error when using xfreerdp
Distribution: Ubuntu
Command: sudo xfreerdp /v:192.168.178.152 /u:steen /p:password1234
Expected output: rdp window
Output:
[17:22:48:028] [441:442] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - transport_write:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_TRANSPORT_FAILED [0x0002000D]
[17:22:48:039] [441:442] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - BIO_should_retry returned a system error 32: Broken pipe
[17:22:48:039] [441:442] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - transport_write:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_TRANSPORT_FAILED [0x0002000D]
[17:22:48:039] [441:442] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_post_connect failed


What research have you done and what have you tried so far?
